# ¿Como imprimir correctamente los datos de un array con objetos?

Tags: javascript

tengo este array que almacena alumnos y profesores, los profesores deben ser los mismos a la hora de asignarlos a los alumnos, el caso es que no logro ser capaz de que hacer que el programa me cargue los prompt para poder hacer que el array alumnos donde inserte todos los alumnos que me vaya creando y que pida el nombre de usuario y muestre la información. adjunto el codigo que creo que me falla es parte del archivo de JavaScript

```
function profesor(nombre, asignatura){
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.asignatura = asignatura;
    
      function nombre() {
        var nombre = [];
        var cont = '';
        var x;
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:", "");
            nombre.push(x);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            cont += nombre[i] + " ";
        }
    
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
    }
      
      function asignatura() {
        var asignatura = [];
        var cont = '';
        var x;
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x = prompt("Ingresa tu asignatura:", "");
            asignatura.push(x);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            cont += asignatura[i] + " ";
        }
    
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
      }
    
    }
    
    function Alumno(nombre, edad, nota, profesor){
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.nota = nota;
      this.profesor = profesor;
    
      function nombre() {
        var nombre = [];
        var cont = '';
        var x;
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:", "");
            nombre.push(x);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            cont += nombre[i] + " ";
        }
    
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
    }
    
      function edad() {
        var edad = [];
        var cont = '';
        var x;
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x = prompt("Ingresa tu edad:", "");
            edad.push(x);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            cont += edad[i] + " ";
        }
    
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
      }
    
      function nota() {
        var nota = [];
        var cont = '';
        var x;
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x = prompt("Ingresa tu nota:", "");
            nota.push(x);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            cont += nota[i] + " ";
        }
    
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
      }
    
      function profesor() {
        var profesor = [];
        var cont = '';
        var x;
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre:", "");
            profesor.push(x);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            cont += profesor[i] + " ";
        }
    
        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = cont;
      }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: No necesitas publicar *tanto* código, sólo necesitas un MCVE. Te invito a que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código relevante, de lo contrario mucho me temo que tu pregunta termine cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Ahora ya esta mejor